# Finding rate limit of docker loggged in user

Tags: docker

This command works as expected and returns the rate limit of 100.

```
TOKEN=$(curl "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:ratelimitpreview/test:pull" | jq -r .token)

curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ratelimitpreview/test/manifests/latest 2>&1 | grep RateLimit
```

But if I need to know the logged-in user rate limit, I try this command. It returns empty value.

```
TOKEN=$(curl --user 'user:PassWd' "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:ratelimitpreview/test:pull" | jq -r .token)
```

I got these commands from official docker blog at:

https://www.docker.com/blog/checking-your-current-docker-pull-rate-limits-and-status/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. For an anonymous user, I got a response with the limit. But when I tried for a specific user that has no limits, I received an empty response.

In your case, it's probably because there are no limits for the provided user.